# Is it possible to read Webmin logs directly from within Bash?

Tags: webmin

I usually access each of Webmin's logs from Webmin itself, but for some reason I can't access the program.

Is there a way to access any of these logs from Bash? I just want Webmin's explanation of what went wrong when I tried to log into it several times with a **correct** username and password, an action that went just fine in previous installations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accessed Webmin WHM error log via:

```
cat /var/webmin/webmin.log
```

One might need to turn on logging and only then repea the error-causing actions → otherwise a `webmin.log` file wont exist in its relevant system.

One can turn on logging from `Webmin → Webmin Configuration → Logging`.
<sub>There might be a way to turn these directly from Bash but I didn't find such a way.</sub>

### Accessing Webmin web server log:

```
cat /var/webmin/miniserv.log
```

### Further way to track errors is:

```
cat /var/webmin/miniserv.error
```

### Notes:

- If one looks for files in `/var/webmin` o system and cannot find them, cheeking in `/var/log/webmin` instead might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, always forget where the real detail is (miniserv), SSL cert error in my case after server migration, destroys apache + webmin :'(